# (Blender Internal) How to apply chroma key to videos playing on planes?

Tags: animation

I have a greens screen video of smoke and want to make it green screened on a plane so it's just the smoke, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: As far as I know you apply chroma key to the video *before* applying it to a plane. When you apply it to the plane it should already be pre-processed.

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=chroma%20key%20in%20blender

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/compositing-video-layers-in-3d-space

Comment: also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39746/1853