# Overlay PNG image as overlay in camera view in BGE

Tags: game-engine

Is there a way to put a PNG image as overlay in the camera view? I want the cross hairs to show in the camera view in Blender Game Engine.

Blender camera view: 
[image: Blender Camera View]

PNG image with overlay:
[image: Overlay]

End product:
[image: End Produc]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got it, you could parent a plane that uses the image as texture (textured using alpha), like this:

[image]

start enabling the "import images as planes" addon (bundled by default), and import your overlay image

[image]

then enable alpha for the texture if needed, and transparency for the material

[image]

then look at the camera rotation transforms

[image]

and copy those values to the plane, and then move it towards the camera (translating on its local Z), to get:

[image]

in the end, here is an example of the camera rotating around a target object, and the view looking through the camera:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. How did you insert the image to the scene? Did you apply it to a plane?

Comment: For a detailed description on how to set this up read: [Create a plane that always fits the camera viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13692/create-a-plane-that-always-fits-the-camera-viewport/13694?noredirect=1#comment180594_13694)

Comment: @fonsi you need to activate the "import images as planes" addon, in user preferences, then import your image and set transparency to mayerial/texture. Then, you need to "parent" the plane to the camera, and set its same rotation values, and place the plane right in front of it.  I'll add detailed steps, later, if needed.

Comment: @fonsi see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you @m.ardito. It worked. I had to adjust the material and texture properties but got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Good! If it solved your issue, please consider marking my answer as "accepted"...